# Select in Oracle is fast only at first execution

Tags: oracle, performance, select

I have a query over a view. At the first execution the querytime is 3 seconds. At the second execution the query doesn't come back.
I tested this query on another database, the same results appeared.
I changed the query and used a Hint `/*+ INDEX (h xdst_pst_e_index)*/`. In one of the two databases the query is now fast at every execution. But in the other one only the first execution is fast. 
There is another strange behaviour:

- Create the select
- execute it (Executiontime 3 secons)
- execute it again (Query doesn't come back)
- change the select (add a blank, I don't change the View)
- execute it (Execution time 3 seconds)
- execute it again (Query doesn't come back)

The Database with this behavior is Oracle 11.2.0.4.0, the one with fast executions is 11.2.0.2.0.

Any idea? I rebuilt the index and the statistics are up to date. The Explainplan is always the same.

Comment: check output of `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('your_sql_id', null));`. Symptoms are typical for cardinality feedback

Comment: Yes, share the plan from both the databases please. Did you rebuild index and refresh stats in both databases?

Comment: Thanks for Feedback. I changed the parameter optimizer_use_feedback in my Session and the statement runs 3 seconds in every execution. I thought about the hint in my statement to control this parameter but the database parameter optimizier_ignore_hints is true in this installation. Maybe i can change these parameters for the whole system, but i have no idea what happens with other statements. Maybe this one is fast and others become slow.

Comment: Consider creating [extended statistics](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/extended_statistics)